# SSMS 2008 R2 Attempting to run a new query tries to connect to SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The problem I'm having is very strange behavior when I connect to my remote production Database. When I start up `SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2` my new query window opens disconnected and every new query window I open is also disconnected; though when I right-click and choose connection, I get Disconnect and Change connection as options not "Connect".

When I try and create a new query window OR if I right-click change connection, `SSMS` opens a dialog with `"connect to SQL Server Compact"`. With everything I have tried I cannot seem to solve this one. However, if I open a `.sql` file `SSMS` opens a connection to my production DB with no problem; I just cant open new/blank query connections to it.

I do not have `SQL Server Compact` installed; I have reinstalled `SQL Server 2008 R2`. The installation was done from an MSDN download of the full version of SSMS; the information from about is as follows:

**Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                        10.50.2550.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        10.50.2500.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML
3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0

So all in all my question is how do I stop this from happening?

Please help; thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you restart SSMS and select "Database Engine" for the server type on the connection dialog?

Comment: @datadamnation; I have not had a chance to try this yet due to work, but will give it a shot later today.

Comment: @datadamnation: The option to select "Database Engine" is greyed out all I get is "SQL Server Compact" in that dialog box.

Comment: So an interesting development, if I tell SSMS to open a .sql file it opens a connection to the SQL Server I connected to from the get go. However, any attempt to open a new query window results in the same attempt to force me to connect to SQL Compact...baffled.

Comment: Does anyone have any information or suggestions that might help me? I'm truly stuck.